# MATLAB Coder giving out-of-bounds error for struct

Tags: matlab, struct, mex, matlab-coder

I am trying to MEX some code by using MATLAB's coder toolkit. The code initially had cell arrays in it which is not handled by the coder at the moment, so I decided to use structs in compensation for that.

My issue is that the size of the struct is not fixed, and herein lies the problem. What I have essentially is this:

```
Temp= struct('a',"some variable");
for i = 2:x
    Temp(j).('a') = Temp(i-1).('a')*Temp(1).('a');
end
```

In the command window of MATLAB, this would be completely acceptable, however when trying to build the MEX file, it throws this error:

**Index expression out of bounds. Attempted to access element 2. The valid range is 1-1.**

Is there a way to fix this, or is there another solution to 'cell array' like structures that the coder will allow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `repmat`:

```
MyStruct = repmat(Temp,1,N);
```

where `N` is a constant (i.e. hard-coded, not data-dependent).
Then, if you wish,

```
for i=2:N
    MyStruct(i).a = MyStruct(i-1).a*MyStruct(1).a;
end
```

No need for `MyStruct(i).('a')`

Comment: +1 here are some relevant links to docs: [Define Arrays of Structures for Code Generation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/defining-arrays-of-structures-for-code-generation.html), [Index Substructures and Fields](http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/indexing-substructures-and-fields.html#zmw57dd0e41076_block). Any way, it seems to me that the entire structure could be replaced with a regular numeric array

Comment: @Amro: For the simple example the OP provided, I agree.

Comment: @ThP That worked thanks! I now have another problem though. Some of the variables I am trying to store in struct are complex. It now comes up with the error saying: "Cannot assign a complex value into a non-complex location." Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @GBoggs: try initializing with a complex constant when you first create the structure, so something like: `Temp = struct('a',complex(0,0));`. See: [Code Generation for Complex Data](http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/code-generation-for-complex-data.html)

Comment: @Amro Yup that did it thanks! I'm sorry but another error came up, and this is for a different part of the code: "Dimension 1 is fixed on the left-hand side but varies on the right ([1 x 1] ~= [:? x :?])." I believe that the variable is just being reassigned to a matrix but its initialized as 0. Is there a way for this to be fixed?

Comment: @GBoggs: See this page: [Diagnose and Fix Variable-Size Data Errors](http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/troubleshooting-issues-with-variable-size-data.html). Also read the section in the docs that explains [variable-size data](http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/variable-size-data.html).